# Why can't I do a phone call in Google Voice?

Tags: gmail, google-voice

I'm wondering why I can only place phone calls in Gmail, not in Google Voice, since phone calls seem to be more of a "voicey" thing than an "emaily" thing.

True, you can *initiate* phone calls from Google Voice, but they connect to Gmail or your phone to do the actual call.

So why is Google Voice not a host for phone calls, but Gmail is? Or am I missing something? (It seems counter-intuitive to me to go to my email to make a phone call... I go to Google Voice to manage my texts and voicemails anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Voice is a voip service which relies on the Jabber protocol (which is what Google Chat is using). Google Chat which is built within Gmail means that your calls will use that if it open and you also selected that option.

Untill Google puts a Google Chat feature like on Gmail on the Google Voice page, you will have to use the options below:

---

You can place calls in Gmail, on www.google.com/voice, using any phone, or Android/iPhone

This is to place calls on www.google.com/voice has different option on dropdown

Call using google chat (gmail)   [Using Google Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1W2O.png)

It will call you then connect to someone else   [Have Google Call You](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1AmB.png)

If using a phone to call your own GV:

If calling from you forwarded number it will ask for your PIN

If calling from another, when voice mail comes on press * the your PIN